# Javascript: How can I optimize this line for performance?

Tags: javascript, performance, for-loop

I would like to optimize the second line in my for loop(var phase). I believe moving parts of it outside of the loop would optimize performance. What can I move outside the for loop to improve performance?

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
var phase = Math.sin((document.body.scrollTop / 1250) + (i % 5));
//var phase = 0.31456656061611776 + (i % 5);
items[i].style.left = items[i].basicLeft + 100 * phase + 'px';
}
```

Comment: @dsg Is every optimization question a code review question?

Comment: You move everything out of the loop that does not depend on `i`.

Comment: So, this code causes problems in your application?

Comment: I don't think this would do well on Code Review, likely get closed as stub code, unless more context is provided, e.g., the rest of the module/function.

Comment: I do not believe that this is what is slowing down your script. There is nothing in here that is overly complex (and v8 would probably optimize the loop for you anyway).

Comment: it's probably worse, but it would also be possible to get rid of the modulo.

Comment: why was it closed? I think if left doesn't affect top then there is a really good answer... which i head already written and can't post now

Answer (score 1):

May be slightly faster:

```
var l = items.length,
    s = (document.body.scrollTop / 1250),
    phase;

for (var i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
  phase = Math.sin(s + (i % 5));
  items[i].style.left = items[i].basicLeft + 100 * phase + 'px';
}
```

However you will most likely not notice the difference, unless you have millions of items.

**Update**: After a few benchmarks that seems to be around 7% faster but only starting to take seconds past 1 million elements.

Comment: If only `document.body.scrollTop` does not depend on `items[X].style.left` which in general cannot be guaranteed.

Comment: Well I'm assuming `left` affect either a `relative` or `absolute` element position hence shouldn't modify the scroll (especially a scrollTop, which is vertical). However if that is the case there is indeed not much that can be done.